# Stata 13 too many variables specified with predict

Tags: stata, predict

I am trying to follow with a simple linear regression example provided by Stata: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HafqFSB9x70](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HafqFSB9x70)

It is done using Stata/SE 12 and works perfectly. 
I am using Stata/MP 13.
And I am getting the following error:

```
. predict Predicted Wage, xb
too many variables specified
r(103);
```

I tried to look this up, couldn't figure it out.
How can I fix this, does this relate to the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predict` takes one new variable name, and you gave it two: `Predicted` and `Wage`. Try deleting the space between them, making `PredictedWage` one word.

Comment: This is correct. Note that the version of Stata is irrelevant here. The underscore `_` may also be used in variable names.